# Mongoose validators not updated

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose and the npm package `mongoose-unique-validator` for validation.

It worked just fine when plugged into my schema, but I changed the validation from an attribute to another one. And now I am still getting the unique mongo error for that old validation (MongoError 11000) for the email... although I moved it to the username, as if the validators from before was not removed and not properly updated.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const uniqueValidator = require('mongoose-unique-validator');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let userSchema = new Schema({
    username:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true,
        uniqueCaseInsensitive: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}
userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator, {message : 'username must be unique'});

module.exports.User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Is there a way to update the validators ? I haven't found anything yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please drop your collections completely, and run your project again. After that every things will be OK, because unique index created in your mongodb based on your email and still exists...

for delete index you can use a IDE for mongodb like robo 3t or ...
with command you can drop a index

```
db.getCollection('CollocationName').dropIndex( "indexName_1" )
```

for you is :

```
db.getCollection('users').dropIndex( "email_1" )
```

if index is created by mongoose you should use indexName with _1